# Dual clock on OxygenOS lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, clock, oneplus-two

I've got the new OnePlusTwo with Android 5.1.1 and OxygenOS 2.1.2. Does anyone know how to display home and roaming clocks on lockscreen? 
That was basic on Galaxy S5, but haven't found out how to do it with this one.